# adding an if statement within brakets in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have the following in my view .html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag :action=>"edit", :id => @product.id do %>
```

I want to basically only add the id if @product exists (not null i suppose) so i want to do something along the lines of:

```
<%= form_tag :action=>"edit" if @product print",:id => @product.id" end do %>
```

I know the above is wrong code but that's the idea behind it, not sure if i can embed that within the <%= tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<%= form_tag :action=>"edit", :id => (@product.id if @product) do %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
url_options = { :action => "edit" }
html_options = {}

html_options[:id] = @product.id if @product
%>

<%= form_tag url_options, html_options do %>    
  <% .... %>
<% end %>
```

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag
- http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<% if @product %>

    <%= form_tag :action=>"edit",:id => @product.id" do %>

<% else %>

    <%= form_tag :action=>"edit" do %>

<% end %>
```

You can probably embed the conditional code in the <%= ... %> tag if you use eval but the above might be more clear!